# array with index in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have this type:

```
export interface ZonesRepresentation {
  zones?: {
    [index: string]: ZonesFieldRepresentation[];
  };
}

export interface ZonesFieldRepresentation {
  id?: string;
  name?: string;
  level?: number;
  zones?: {
    [index: string]: ZonesFieldRepresentation[];
  };
}
```

Here the const using the declared type:

```
export const [locations] = useState<ZonesRepresentation>({});
```

And here the function using the locations const:

```
export const level0: () => { [index: string]: ZonesFieldRepresentation[] } =
  function (): { [index: string]: ZonesFieldRepresentation[] } {
    return locations.zones;
  };
```

The function compiles with an error:

Type '{ [index: string]: ZonesFieldRepresentation[]; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ [index: string]: ZonesFieldRepresentation[]; }'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ [index: string]: ZonesFieldRepresentation[]; }'.

Why? How I resolve this error?

Comment: `locations.zones` is `zones?` so it can be `undefined` so you should `if (!locations.zones) throw new Error()` or `return undefined` or whatever